Error when processing Data File with a Streamlit App
I am trying to deploy an app which processes a .csv data file inputted by the user and performs some dimensional analysis with it and produces plots.  The Github repo can be found at 1.
The file which I run is called ‘‘streamlitstuff.py’’ and the other file on the repo which has errors is the data reader file ‘‘data_reader.py’’.
The website is created as expected but when I try to input a .csv data file in the required format I receive the below error messages, can anyone advise?  I have also attached an image for what is seen on the website with the same message.
Although there is a message about the index being out of range, I have used this data file before with a previous version of the code about two years ago so there has been some bug in the code which developed since then or something which no longer works and needs to be changed.  From looking at the data table on the left-hand side where there are alternating rows of ''None'', it looks like something is wrong with how the indexing of the rows is done.
File “C:\Users\holli\miniconda3\Lib\site-packages\streamlit\runtime\scriptrunner\script_runner.py”,
line 600, in _run_script
exec(code, module.dict)
File “C:\Users\holli\streamlitstuff.py”, line 61, in
data = Data(ds, pandas=True)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File “C:\Users\holli\data_reader.py”, line 12, in init
self.parameters = self.generate_list_of_parameters()
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File “C:\Users\holli\data_reader.py”, line 24, in generate_list_of_parameters
units=getattr(Units(), key.split(‘-’)[1]),
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^
IndexError: list index out of range


Edit: Since the error seems to be related to the call for key.split I have added the full code snippet of this part from data_reader.py.
  def generate_list_of_parameters(self):
parameters = ListOfParameters([])
for key in self.data:
parameters.append(Parameter(value=[value for value in self.data[key]],
units=getattr(Units(), key.split('-')[1]),
name=key.split('-')[0]))
return parameters

2nd edit:
Using the below block of code the app is produced, but when I input a .csv data file I receive the error message
AttributeError: 'Data' object has no attribute 'generate_list_of_parameters'.
I have tried to set up the Data class as follows:
class Data:
def __init__(self, file, pandas=False):
    self.file_location = '' if pandas else file
    self.data = file if pandas else self.read_file(self.file_location)
    self.parameters = self.generate_list_of_parameters()


the error message that seems to be coming up, IndexError: list index out of range, is probably caused by trying to access an element of a list using an index that does not exist. In your file: data_reader.py this is happening at the line where key.split('-')[1] is called. the main problem and what you did wrong was you assumed that every key in the data has a hyphen (-) separating the parameter name and the unit type without checking if this format is consistently followed. and wiht the units you used getattr(Units(), key.split('-')[1]) to dynamically retrieve unit attributes. If the unit type did not exist in the Units class, this would raise an AttributeError. and last you had
no error handling to manage situations where the unit type was not found in the Units class. here is the correct code(I hope):
import pandas as pd
from units import Units
from convert import Convert, ConvertTemperature
from parameter import Parameter, ListOfParameters
from buckingham_pi_theorem.dimensional_analysis import DimensionalAnalysis
class Data:
def __init__(self, file, pandas=False):
        self.file_location = '' if pandas else 
file
        self.data = file if pandas else 
self.read_file(self.file_location)
        self.parameters = 
self.generate_list_of_parameters()

@staticmethod
def read_file(file_location):
    data = pd.read_csv(file_location)
    return data

def generate_list_of_parameters(self):
    parameters = ListOfParameters([])
    for key in self.data:
        try:
            print(f"Processing key: {key}")  # Debugging statement
            parts = key.split('-')
            if len(parts) > 1 and parts[1]:  # Check if there's a valid second part
                unit_key = parts[1]
                unit = getattr(Units, unit_key, None)
                if unit is not None:
                    parameters.append(Parameter(value=[value for value in self.data[key]],
                                                units=unit,
                                                name=parts[0]))
                else:
                    print(f"Attribute '{unit_key}' not found in Units class")
            else:
                print(f"Key '{key}' does not have a valid second part after hyphen")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error processing key '{key}': {e}")
    return parameters

if __name__ == "__main__":
experiment = Data("C:/Users/truma/Downloads/test - bernoulli_v2.csv")
d = DimensionalAnalysis(experiment.parameters)
d.plot()

values = [80, 20, 9.8, 1, 1, 1]
test = ListOfParameters([])
for i, parameter in enumerate(experiment.parameters[1:]):
    test.append(Parameter(value=values[i], units=parameter.units, name=parameter.name))
print('test', test)

PLEASE NOTE THAT IMPORTS ARE NOT IN THIS CODE AND WILL HAVE TO BE ADDED!
If you're using Streamlit and running into issues with importing the Data class from your file, make sure the file structure and import statements are correctly set up for example:
import streamlit as st
from data_reader import Data

def main():
    st.title("Dimensional Analysis Tool")
    uploaded_file = st.file_uploader("Choose a CSV file", type="csv")
if uploaded_file is not None:
    data = Data(uploaded_file, pandas=True)  # Assuming the CSV file is processed as a pandas DataFrame
    st.write(data.data)
    # Perform further analysis and display results

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


I have added the full part of the code which involves this line, are you able to advise what goes wrong with the indexing?

I tried using a different data file and the error message was for the same part of the code, but now it says 'Unit' object is not callable, so not sure what is going on.

The error i think occurs when you are trying to call an object that is not callable. this might be related to how you are using the Units class.

and are you able to provide the code so i cna see whats going wrong and where

I added the part with the Units class at the bottom of my post.

Here is the link to the data_reader.py file in the GitHub repo https://github.com/FluidsLab/fluid_ws/blob/main/data_reader.py

i have added code now

I ran the modified code but had the error message added to the second edit on the original post.

File "C:\Users\holli\data_reader.py", line 11
self.data = file if pandas else
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

I changed self,file in line 9 to self.file and it said   File "C:\Users\holli\data_reader.py", line 9
def init(self.file, pandas=False):
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

I tried changing the def_init part to the original part and got an error message  'Data' object has no attribute 'generate_list_of_parameters'.

The error thats happening is due to a typo in the method definition of the init constructor in the Data class.  the method signature should be def init(self, file, pandas=False):, not def init(self.file, pandas=False):.
i have added the corrcted version of you code now

So I am using your first block of text and have checked that the Data class is imported correctly. It works and the app is generated but when I input a data file it says AttributeError: 'Data' object has no attribute 'generate_list_of_parameters'.

The error message AttributeError: 'Data' object has no attribute 'generate_list_of_parameters' suggests that the method generate_list_of_parameters is not defined within the Data class.  ensure the method is correctly defined within the Data class and that the indentation and structure of the code are correct. i have updated the code again

I tried your part of the code with the Data class but it did not work because of the indentations. I have added my own version to the original post, I am not sure why this would not work for defining generate_list_of_parameters.

OK everything works now when I use a data file which separates with the hyphen.  I still need to add useful error messages for when someone inputs a data file without the hyphen convention or the next person to use it will have the same problems all over again.
